# Map ftp servers as network drives in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, mount, network-shares

I'm a new Linux user, just switched over from Windows. I've got a couple FTP servers I connect to on a regular basis through sftp. I was wondering if there was a way to, as we say in windows, **map them as network drives** in Linux, so I can just copy stuff into a drive or folder and it will just map it to the server by ftp. That would be pretty cool. Anybody know how this would be possible, and how to do it? I Can't see to find anything in the literature.

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Open Nautilus("File Browser"). File->Connect to server. Choose FTP (with login) and enter the right information and add something in the "bookmark name" field. Then you can access the FTP server, browse it and edit the files directly.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [**CurlFtpFS**](http://packages.debian.org/testing/utils/curlftpfs). It allows you to mount remote FTP hosts as local directories.

Comment: looks like there's also one called Sshfs

Comment: ssh is not quite ftp.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Midnight Commander is pretty handy with FTP as well.  The package is called "mc".  It's a terminal-based (curses) GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to SFTP servers, then your connection should be an SSH one. Although this is rather a slower connection type, and I prefer NFS or even SMB, it works fine for transferring files, managing them, etc. In the "Connect to server, choose SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually still pretty broken at them moment (see date), the vast majority of users wanting it want a passive FTP connnection seamlessly as for sftp.

The workaround is to use other software such as FileZilla, but this is poor functionality this many years in. Given that a number of major vendors still maintain FTP repositories, this should just work, and continue to work for the immediate future.